# C++ conditional wait race condition

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

Suppose that I have a program that has a worker-thread that squares number from a queue. The problem is that if the work is to light (takes to short time to do), the worker finishes the work and notifies the main thread before it have time to even has time to wait for the worker to finish.

My simple program looks as follows:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>

std::atomic<bool> should_end;

std::condition_variable work_to_do;
std::mutex work_to_do_lock;

std::condition_variable fn_done;
std::mutex fn_done_lock;
std::mutex data_lock;

std::queue<int> work;
std::vector<int> result;

void worker() {
    while(true) {
        if(should_end) return;

        data_lock.lock();
        if(work.size() > 0) {
            int front = work.front();
            work.pop();
            if (work.size() == 0){
                fn_done.notify_one();
            }
            data_lock.unlock();
            result.push_back(front * front);


        } else {
            data_lock.unlock();

            // nothing to do, so we just wait
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(work_to_do_lock);
            work_to_do.wait(lck);
        }
    }
}


int main() {

    should_end = false;
    std::thread t(worker); // start worker

    data_lock.lock();
    const int N = 10;
    for(int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
        work.push(i);
    }
    data_lock.unlock();

    work_to_do.notify_one(); // notify the worker that there is work to do
    //if the worker is quick, it signals done here already
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(fn_done_lock);
    fn_done.wait(lck);

    for(auto elem : result) {
        printf("result = %d \n", elem);
    }

    work_to_do.notify_one(); //notify the worker so we can shut it down
    should_end = true;

    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your *actual* question?

Comment: This is because the shown approach is fundamentally flawed, in more than one way. Too many to worth discussing. There are plenty of examples on the Interwebs of correctly implementing the producer/consumer multithreaded semantics. Why couldn't you base your code on any of them, instead of trying to come up with your own approach.

Comment: "_the worker finishes the work and notifies the main thread before it have time to even has time to wait for the worker to finish._" Why aren't you using the 2nd form, of `wait`, which takes predicate, then?

Comment: or use a condition_variable https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable or a complete example at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60363/thread-pool-worker-implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your try to use notification itself over conditional variable as a flag that job is done is fundamentally flawed. First and foremost `std::conditional_variable` can have spurious wakeups so it should not be done this way. You should use your queue size as an actual condition for end of work, check and modify it under the same mutex protected in all threads and use the same mutex lock for condition variable. Then you may use `std::conditional_variable` to wait until work is done but you do it after you check queue size and if work is done at the moment you do not go to wait at all. Otherwise you check queue size in a loop (because of spurious wakeups) and wait if it is still not empty or you use `std::condition_variable::wait()` with a predicate, that has the loop internally.